# Dynamically creating CustomValidator in server control

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, custom-validators, naming-containers

I have a custom server control which wraps a RadEditor (basically a textarea).  I am trying to add a CustomValidator to it dynamically, but I keep getting this error on initial pageload

> Unable to find control id 'RadEditor1' referenced by the
>   'ControlToValidate' property of ''.

This is the code I'm using inside my server control to create the CustomValidator:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    var validator = new CustomValidator();
    validator.CssClass = "validator-error";
    validator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
    validator.ControlToValidate = this.ID;
    validator.Text = "You've exceeded the maximum allowed length for this field";
    validator.ClientValidationFunction = "checkLength";

    this.Controls.Add(validator);

    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

Comment: Does your server control derive from `RadEditor`?

Comment: Yes, it does.  `public class RichTextEditor : RadEditor {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `RadEditor` implements `INamingContainer`, so ASP.NET winds up searching among your server control's *children* for a control named `RadEditor1`. Of course, it's unsuccessful because `RadEditor1` doesn't have a child control named `RadEditor1`.

The trick I use is to choose a special ID like `"."` to mean the parent control itself:

```
protected override Control FindControl(string id, int pathOffset)
{
    return (id == ".") ? this : base.FindControl(id, pathOffset);
}
```

Then use `"."` as the `ControlToValidate`:

```
validator.ControlToValidate = ".";
```

Comment: Brilliant.  Worked perfectly.

Comment: Add a ".." for referring to the parent. Might be useful one day. :)